# Buttons/keyboard shortcuts for subscripts/superscripts

Tags: feature-request, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes certain posts, especially in scientific forums, use a lot of subscripted/superscripted characters which need not be rendered in TeX. In such cases it is a pain to keep typing (or even pasting) `<sub> </sub>` all the time. Most users are also unaware of this HTML feature and I end up spending quite some time editing their posts.

This is also an issue when excerpts that contain extensive subscripts/superscripts are pasted (At least in excerpts from scientific articles).

For an example, see this excerpt from a scientific article, that I pasted in one of my [posts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/36129/3340):

> Schematic representation of a convex cone characterized by five
>   extreme pathways. Extreme Pathways 1–5 (EP<sub>1</sub>, EP<sub>2</sub>, EP<sub>3</sub>, EP<sub>4</sub>, and EP<sub>5</sub>)
>   circumscribe the solution space for the three fluxes indicated (v<sub>A</sub>,
>   v<sub>B</sub>, v<sub>C</sub>). EP<sub>4</sub> lies in the plane formed by fluxes v<sub>A</sub> and v<sub>B</sub>.
>   Consequently, flux v<sub>C</sub> does not participate in that extreme pathway.
>   EP<sub>3</sub>, EP<sub>4</sub>, and EP<sub>5</sub> are all close and represent different uses of a
>   network to achieve a similar overall result. All points within the
>   convex cone can be described as a non-negative linear combination of
>   the extreme pathways [<sup>[**1**]</sup>](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/12/12/1889.full).

It could be noted that there are not just numerical subscripts but alphabetical too. Though numerical sub/superscript UTF characters can be generated by using compose keys, it is not possible for alphabetical subscripts. Moreover, UTF looks ugly.

---

UTF: ³A₅

HTML: <sup>3</sup>A<sub>5</sub>

---

In general, sites like chemistry and biology use a lot of references to chemicals using their formulae (inline references). Usage of TeX makes the *TeXxed* text blatantly stand out which is not necessary when you just want to write "CO<sub>2</sub>" to say carbon dioxide.

---

Would it be feasible to add keyboard shortcuts or format buttons for wrapping subscript and superscript HTML tags?

Comment: If you are on Linux or similar, take a look at the Compose feature. It essentially intellegently combines standard characters after you press a designated *compose* key. E.g., <compose> + <_> + <4> yields ₄. Some similar feature may exist on other operating systems.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I know about compose keys but UTF does not have alphabetical sub/superscripts and also the UTF characters don't look that good. It is fine for comments and title but not for the body.

Answer (score 2):

In the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release), the shortcuts for the Superscript <kbd>Ctrl-.</kbd> and Subscript <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd> are introduced.
Reference: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51
Using the new shortcuts you are able to create the Superscript and Subscript texts in the editor.

**Screenshot for reference:** [image: Superscript, Subscript image]

**GIF for reference:** [image: Superscript, Subscript gif]