# Superscript / subscript editor buttons on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, editor

I think, at least on certain sites (Chemistry in particular), the mobile editor could really benefit from superscript and subscript buttons.

Using Chemistry as an example, superscript and subscript are a *very* common formatting need, but typing the HTML tags on mobile keyboards (well at least on the default Android one) is super tedious, the angle brackets being the biggest offender:

[image: attempt at subscripts on a phone to show difficulty]

So yeah, that. Maybe not globally, but definitely on certain sites.

Btw I did see [Buttons/keyboard shortcuts for subscripts/superscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261363/230261) but, it's kinda old and here I'm really just requesting it for the mobile site.

PS Said buttons should work even when no text is selected: insert tags and position cursor inside them.

---

(Actually, I'm only really thinking of the Chemistry site, but I'm sure there are others.)

Comment: No. It doesn't. I mentioned that. :)

Comment: While I can understand your point of view, it's basically the same feature request. Yes, you're asking for those controls to just be on the mobile site (which is deprecated and not even getting bug fixes, let alone new features). I've assumed you meant just showing the controls at narrow screen widths, which are presumably on a mobile device, with the responsive design, but doing that doesn't really make a lot of sense, given that the wider widths have the space for the controls, but narrow widths are harder to have more controls.

Comment: ‍♂️ I posted it then set it free.

Comment: It's easier to [do it in MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4725/73620), but [you can use Unicode in titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2691/73620).

Comment: @Rob Oh sweet the mathjax is easier, ty.

Comment: Jason, remember that mhchem is enabled on Chemistry.SE by default (and can be user enabled page by page on any of our other MathJax sites). It allows a very powerful set of chemical engineering notation: https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/ - it certainly makes it a more complicated solution, with the reward of beauty (and it's the correct way to do it on that site).

Comment: Also see: "[Introducing: Markdown Shortcuts for Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4264/73620)", a customizable macro UserScript for posts, comments, and chat (with MathJax support). Direct Link: https://stackapps.com/q/7930/58236

Comment: Re *"Using Chemistry as an example, superscript and subscript are a very common formatting need"*: It is automatic on that site (mhchem). [Example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159585/): `$\ce{C4H8Br2}$` ([butyldibromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyl_group)(?)) gets properly formatted - explicit (subscript) formatting is not necessary.

Comment: @Rob things like typing specialized unicode chars, userscripts, etc are a challenge on mobile, but the mathjax and mlchem formatting is a definite improvement over typing html.

Comment: Jason, for super/subscript Unicode characters you can bookmark this webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts or another of your preference. The reason for using Unicode is so that your formula will display correctly on (search engines and) **all** site's Hot Network Questions list, when MathJax is not enabled for that webpage. --- Using m**h**chem is correct and shouldn't be edited out by the pedantic; to show up *better* off-site. --- If you are involved with a few of our tech sites and/or write papers using LaTex, MathJax pays off. HTML isn't near as useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tbh, if I'm going to open the menu, tap bookmarks, tap that page, scroll down, select text, tap copy, tap the tabs button, switch back to the editor tab, tap the text twice then tap paste, I think I'd rather just type html tags, lol. 

Comment: (Most of the good desktop solutions don't work well on mobile; or more accurately they work fine but I am too easily frustrated by tedium, heh. That's part of the main reason why I initially posted this as its own thing instead of the other post, that along with the mobile site being its own separate thing. .)